# Highlighting macros and keynames containing asterisk

Tags: listings

My goal is to highlight latex macros and keynames in the MWE below. The problems come in when `*` is a part of a keyname and also as an argument to a macro.

I tried using the MWE, but it does not highlight `\mymacro` on the first line

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset
{
    basicstyle = {\ttfamily},
    alsoletter =  {\\,-,*},
    keywords = [0]{key-*},
    keywordstyle = [0]{\color{blue}},
    keywords = [1]{\\mymacro},
    keywordstyle = [1]{\color{red}}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}
        \mymacro*[key-*=true]{y}{x}
        \mymacro[key-*=true]{y}{x}
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset
{
    basicstyle = {\ttfamily},
    alsoletter =  {\\,-,*},
    keywords = [0]{key-*},
    keywordstyle = [0]{\color{blue}},
    keywords = [1]{\\mymacro,\\mymacro*},
    keywordstyle = [1]{\color{red}}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}
        \mymacro*[key-*=true]{y}{x}
        \mymacro[key-*=true]{y}{x}
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]